# Turtle drawing backwards

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, letter

This is easily the dumbest question I have ever had to ask, but I'm trying to use Turtle to code something that will take English inputs and draw letters in an alphabet I created for a D&D campaign. I'm trying to draw a letter like this:

[Letter I'm trying to draw. Similar to a candy cane?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJDkX.png)

The code I have currently is this:

```
turtle.pendown()
turtle.seth(270)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.back(50)
turtle.seth(90)
turtle.circle(25,150)
```

But the problem is that the result draws what I want *backwards*. I tried changing the heading to everything I can think of, but nothing makes the shape I want. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To arc in a clockwise direction, you can set the radius to be negative

...

`turtle.circle(-25,150)`

Answer (score 0):

`turtle.circle(radius, extent)` draws in a counterclockwise direction for positive values of *radius*.

use negative numbers to draw clockwise.

see the turtle documentation for more https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle

Answer (score 0):

Since you were already heading down, you could stay in that orientation and draw the arc backward (negative extent):

```
turtle.pendown()
turtle.seth(270)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.back(50)
# turtle.seth(90)        <-- don't change direction
turtle.circle(25,-150) # <-- draw arc backward
```